# Как передать значения из frame

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe

По нажатию кнопки открывается фрейм, страница открывается внутренняя. Во фрейме есть несколько кнопок, они не работают, т.е. вообще ничего не происходит по их нажатию. Если переходить на эту страницу без фрейма, то всё нормально работает и кнопки кликабельны

код кнопки во фрейме

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="{$smarty.const.CART_PROCEED_TO_CHECKOUT}" onClick="{if $cart_amount<$smarty.const.CONF_MINIMAL_ORDER_AMOUNT}document.getElementById('id_too_small_order_amount').style.display='block';return false;{/if}window{if $this_is_a_popup_cart_window}.opener{/if}.location='index.php?quick_register=yes';{if $this_is_a_popup_cart_window}window.close();{/if}">
```

код открытия фрейма

```
<a class="iframe" href="cart.php?addproduct={$product_info.productID}">{$smarty.const.ADD_TO_CART_STRING}</a>
```